# Unity 3D Model Y Translation when Switching animations

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I made an animator for my Player Character, I have 2 differents animations.

When I play only one, nothing, it's cool, the character is doing the animation.

```
OwnAnimator.SetBool("running", true);
```

But when I have multiple animation (2), in my AnimatorController, the player goes under the floor instantly at the runtime O_O.

Please someone can help me ? :)

Answer (score 0):

What is your second animation? Since animations can affect the transform position it is possible that your animation changes the Y-axis of the transform.

Comment: I have a first Idle animation, and the second one is Running. When I have only one animation in my animator my Y axis don't move but when I have more than one animation it does. The model is transformed but not the character controller.